# Low power USB C power supply

Tags: power, usb

I am searching for a tiny board to that accepts an usb-c cable and outputs 5v.

To my understanding, for the few hundred milliamps two 5k1 resistors on the board would suffice. PD is not needed.

I already bought [this](https://www.amazon.de/Pololu-Type-C-Connector-Breakout-Board/dp/B07GZKMPJ8/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=usb%20c%20diy%20socket&qid=1603465656&sr=8-1), but sadly it's too big. Also, I don't need any data pins, just 5v and -.

Can anyone recommend such a board to power a tiny circuit?

Comment: If you can't find one, design your own.

Comment: I would, I just  don't have the equipment to assemble it. Also, the project is really not that important...

Comment: Cut the end off a USB C extension cable and wire it in directly.

Comment: takes too much space, sadly...

Comment: More space than the cable you'd be plugging in anyway?

Comment: by extension cable you mean a type c with male on one end and female on the other?

Comment: Yes. Have the socket "remote" from your space constrained device.

Comment: I see. Sadly, that defeats the purpose in my case. I could just aswell cut a male-male cable and hardwire that. Although it's quite creative.

Comment: Have you considered *not* using USB C? There are plenty of other small connectors.

Comment: Sure. Seems like I am falling back to usb micro. I thought that if I am already building a device, it could be C aswell..

Comment: It would make sense from a future-proofing PoV. It's still not common in the arduinosphere though - there's not many boards that use it. I think I only have 2 USB C cables in my possession, and one of those is for a Pi 4.

Comment: I'd cut that board. Solder some wires to the GND and VCC planes. I don't think those resistors are needed if you use less than 100mA. Though I'm not that familiar with USB C. You might be able to move them with some creative soldering.

Comment: sadly, usb c doesn't provide 5v just like that, so some sort of configuration is needed...